# Biased and Unbiased estimators

Tags: statistics

Two independent random samples $X_1, X_2, …, X_n$ and $Y_1, Y_2, …, Y_m$ are taken from a population with mean $μ$ and variance $σ^2$. The unbiased estimators $\bar X$ and $\bar Y$ of $μ$ are calculated. A new unbiased estimator $T$ of $μ$ is sought of the form $T=r\bar X+s\bar Y$.

a) Show that, since $T$ is unbiased $r+s=1$.

b) By writing $T=r\bar X+(1-r)\bar Y$, show that $$Var(T)=σ^2[\frac{r^2}{n}+\frac{(1-r)^2}{m}]$$

c) Show that the minimum variance of $T$ is when $r=\frac{n}{n+m}$

d) Find the best (in the sense of minimum variance) estimator of $μ$ of the form $r\bar X+s\bar Y$.

Please help, I don't understand any of this and every question is like this.
How do I do these?

Edit: What I thought I might have to do:

Part a)

$$\bar X=\frac{ΣX_1+X_2+ …+X_n}{n}$$
$$\bar X=\frac{Σμ+μ+ …+μ}{n}$$
$$\bar X=\frac{nμ}{n}$$
$$\bar X=μ$$
$$\bar Y=\frac{ΣX_1+X_2+ …+X_m}{m}$$
$$\bar Y=\frac{Σμ+μ+ …+μ}{m}$$
$$\bar Y=\frac{mμ}{m}$$
$$\bar Y=μ$$
$$μ(r+s)-μ=0$$
$$r+s=1$$

Part b)

$$Var(T)=\frac{1}{n}Var(r\bar X)+\frac{1}{m}Var((1-r)\bar Y)$$
$$Var(T)=\frac{r^2}{n}Var(\bar X)+\frac{(1-r)^2}{m}Var(\bar Y)$$
$$Var(T)=\frac{r^2}{n}σ^2+\frac{(1-r)^2}{m}σ^2$$
$$Var(T)=σ^2[\frac{r^2}{n}+\frac{(1-r)^2}{m}]$$

I don't know if the above is correct. As for part c and d, I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score -1):

a) Show that $E[T] = \mu$ by linearity of expectation (i.e. $E[ \alpha X + \beta Y] = \alpha E[X] + \beta E[Y]$)$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{Var}}$

b) Use the fact that $\var( \sum_i \alpha_i X_i) = \sum_i \alpha_i \var(X_i)$ to show that $\var(\bar{X}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ (since $\bar{X} = \sum_i X_i / n$) and similarly for $\var(\bar{Y})$. Then, use this fact again to show $\var(T)$ is what is stated.

c) Just minimize the expression in (b). You can use calculus if you want.

d) You in part (a) that you can restrict to r+s=1 (form given in (b)), so use the parameter you found in (c) in the form you found in (b).